# CSS style is missing in all my Django applications

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

Since I started using the Django framework I noticed that the CSS style did not appear when I entered the admin site and others templates and I thought it was normal but with the passage of time I have seen that the applications of my partners did have the style, so I copied their projects on my laptop and I ran them and I could see the CSS style of their applications.
I'm getting data from a database from a server, that's the only difference in how my partners and I have been working.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

PD: I'm working with version 1.8 of Django and version 3.4.4 of python

This is my base of my HTML's code

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DENUE INEGI</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/crm.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphiconlock"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
                <h1><a href="/">Directorio Estadístico Nacional de Unidades Económicas INEGI</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my setting.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

I appreciate your answers, thank you :)

Comment: Please include some code on how you used/included the stylesheet

Comment: Sure, one moment please

Comment: there isn't enough information on your post. show settings file your project. also you can inspect web page with your browser. And see on the errors on the page. Post all this information and we will try to help you

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy Thank you for responding and wanting to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) to serve static files during development you have to:

1) define `STATIC_URL` in settings file - you have it. So you have to create `static` folder in the root of your project.

2) `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

3) In urls.py of you project you have to have this snippet:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
 + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If your project under deployment, then you can serve static files by the web server. Then you don't need snippet in `urls.py`

Hope it helps you

Comment: That has been very helpful to me, I really appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 4):

Try to change Debug = True in your application settings and then check the admin panel.

Comment: That option was by default

Comment: If Allowed_host=["*"] then debug has to be true

Answer (score 0):

Check your `urls.py` with `urls.py` of your friends project. I had the same problem with CSS files. and found answer in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development